# Notification every time wifi disconnects

Tags: java, android

I need my application to give a notification whenever WiFi goes offline.

I got it to give a notification every time the WiFi connection changes. But I need it to only give a notification when it goes offline.

Also it gives a notification on start-up (of the application).

My question is, how do I alter the code to only give a notification when WiFi goes offline? Now it gives a notification when it goes offline, online and on start-up.

The code:

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
     this.registerReceiver(this.mConnReceiver,
        new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     }

     private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
     String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
     boolean isFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);

     NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
     NetworkInfo otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);

     if(currentNetworkInfo.isConnected()){

     }else{
        showNotification();
     }
 }
};
```

Comment: What is your question?  You've shown us some code, but haven't explained what the problem is with it.

Comment: Duplicate of [Notification everytime wifi is disconnected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402544/notification-everytime-wifi-is-disconnected) - Please edit your question rather than posting a new (duplicate) one.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
if(currentNetworkInfo != null &&
     currentNetworkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI &&
     currentNetworkInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTING) {
    showNotification();
}
```

There are also other possible states(such as `NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED`, maybe that is what you want), you can find the full list here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.State.html

Comment: Didn't work. When I turn the wifi off, I get no notification. Thanks for the suggestions though.