# Notification every time wifi is disconnected

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I need my application to give a notification whenever WiFi goes offline.

I got it to give a notification every time the WiFi connection changes. But I need it to only give a notification when it goes offline.

Also it gives a notification on start-up (of the application).

My question is, how do I alter the code to only give a notification when WiFi goes offline? Now it gives a notification when it goes offline, online and on start-up.

The code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        

 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
 this.registerReceiver(this.mConnReceiver,
    new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }

 private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
 String reason = intent.getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
 boolean isFailover = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);

 NetworkInfo currentNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
 NetworkInfo otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);

 if(currentNetworkInfo.isConnected()){
 } 
 else{showNotification();}

 }
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this line in `onReceive()` of `BroadCastReceiver`

```
if(!isNetworkConnectionAvailable(ctx)){
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Network Connection Available ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

the code for isNetworkConnectionAvailable() is

```
    public static boolean isNetworkConnectionAvailable(Context context)
{
    boolean isNetworkConnectionAvailable = false;

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService("connectivity");
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if(activeNetworkInfo != null) 
    {
        isNetworkConnectionAvailable = activeNetworkInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED;
    }
    return isNetworkConnectionAvailable;
}
```

comment me about result

Comment: Got an error on the ctx variable? I'm a complete beginner.

Comment: Using your code and @NARESH REDDY's answer, replace **ctx** with **context**.

Comment: It worked your my hero.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to check connectivity [InetAddress.isReachable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29), the method returns true if you have connectivity else false